# What does "./" do?

Tags: command-line

I've got absolutely no idea what this does and if I search something like "linux ./ command", Google just seems to ignore those two characters as they're puntuation. If someone can give me a simple answer, I'd be very grateful :)

Comment: `./` designates the current working directory...

Answer (score 0):

Couple of commands that could help you on understanding it are,

From any directory (assume `/home/somedir`), run the below commands.

- `stat ./` - It will give out an inode number.
- `find /home -inum inode_number` - It will list the directory from where you originally executed the `stat` command.